# Kafka - move messages to front of queue based on scheduled time

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue

Is there a feature in Kafka (or other message queues) through which we can add messages which will become active only of the time specified. Which means that message should not be consumed before the specified time.

Follow up, is there a way through which we can move those messages to the front of queue when it reaches scheduled time.

Comment: Something to note here is that you are kind of asking for random access, not a queue. A database might just be a better solution. Typically in a Kafka setting, you are streaming data from the end if the log constantly and don't have large bags in consumption, making priority of requests irrelevant. Hiding messages until a specified time is not supported by Kafka but I'd be curious to know the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka cannot do this. Kafka is basically just a commit log which will write the messages in the order in which they are received and read them in he same order.

However other more traditional messaging brokers can do it - for example ActiveMQ Artemis has support for [scheduled messages](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/scheduled-messages.html). I do not think the message will move within the queue, but it will not be consumed before the scheduled time.

Comment: Yes, the difference is in Kafka, the onus of consuming messages is on the consumer, so the consumer decides when it wants to read. In traditional messaging brokers which conform to the JMS spec, the onus is on the server to distribute the messages, so yes u can do it in them.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the Kafka broker itself, but you can do this using [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) by defining a custom [Processor](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/Processor.html), which does the following:

- store each message into a StateStore using the timestamp of when the message should be processed as the key. Since multiple messages may have the same such timestamp, you'll need to wrap them into a collection or suffix the key with some unique value.
- in the [init](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/Processor.html#init-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext-) method schedule a punctuation which periodically does a [ranged query](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.html#range-K-K-) on the state store and [forwards](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html#forward-K-V-) the messages that have reached their timestamp and removes them from the store.
- the forwarded messages will go into a separate topic and the consumers will have to consume from that topic instead but the messages there will be in the order you defined.

Comment: Or you can follow the same idea with KSQL, which is an other abstraction on top of streams, to select all messages older than their including timestamp.